# SSRS email report job uses wrong content type for PDFs

Tags: email, pdf, reporting-services, reporting-services-2012

I have SSRS (2012) configured to auto send reports in PDF format. In GMAIL (android), you cannot click on the reports to open. You need to save to drive and then open from drive. (outlook can open it though)

I think the problem is the content type is wrong.

It sends out as: Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="application/pdf"

It should be: Content-Type: application/pdf; name="application/pdf"

Can anyone assist on how to fix this?
thanks,
Zev.

headers from email. This is the PDF attachment SSRS attached when it sent it.

----boundary_2_ee6bd0fc-4e77-432e-81f4-b678737c8c05
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="application/pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <770d9496-f9ed-45cf-8e20-37667a2cd081>
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="=?utf-8?B?RW1wbG95ZWVzQ2xvY2tlZEluRHluYW1pY0dyb3VwaW5nUmVwb3J0LnBkZg==?="

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f4022fcd-b20f-4d7b-9631-5a931c57980f/attachments-sending-with-different-content-type-after-migration-from-ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2014?forum=sqlreportingservices), the e-mail gets the wrong content type when it gets' modified post-SSRS:

> Update on this - after much experimentation I found that the e-mail
>   gets malformed when something is modifying it in transit after it has
>   left the SSRS server (i.e. gateways adding disclaimers).

This doesn't explain why the issue only seems to have started with SSRS 2012, though.